# Running Yaws Apps

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am quite new to erlang and yaws. I after playing around with the language and easy yaws features like ehtml and normal appmods I tried to write a yapp. I followed http://yaws.hyber.org/yapp_intro.yaws and https://github.com/davide/yawn/wiki to get it more or less running. It simply consists of an .app file and a simple test.erl/beam that just has a out/1.
Yaws starts without a problem and loads the yapp. When I run yaws in the interactive mode and call test:out(somehting) it works fine. When I surf the url (with browser or curl) I get an

```
=ERROR REPORT==== Date ===
Yaws process died:...
```

and nothing returned to the client. I have been trying around a couple of things, but I haven't found the problem yet.

I believe the problem is in my .app file...
I hope you can help my. I added the content of the .app and my localhost-ssl.conf below.

```
marc@server:~$ cat /usr/lib/yaws/lib/api/ebin/api.app 
{application, api,
 [{description,"cloudia api as yapp"},
  {vsn,"0.1"},
  {modules,[]},
  {registered, []},
  {env, [
         {yapp_appmods,[{"/",test}]},
        ]}]}.


marc@server:~$ sudo cat /etc/yaws/conf.d/localhost-ssl.conf
<server localhost>
    port = 443
    listen = 0.0.0.0
    docroot = /usr/share/yaws
    arg_rewrite_mod = api
    #dir_listings = true
    <ssl>  
        keyfile = /etc/yaws/yaws-key.pem
        certfile = /etc/yaws/yaws-cert.pem
    </ssl>   
    <opaque>
    yapp_server_id = edo
    </opaque>
</server>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you carefully follow the [yapp instructions provided at the Yaws website](http://yaws.hyber.org/yapp_intro.yaws) everything should work fine. Be sure to remember to:

- set the global `runmod` configuration variable to `yapp`
- set your server configuration `arg_rewrite_mod` to `yapp`
- within your server configuration `opaque` block, set `bootstrap_yapps` to `yapp`

To avoid the need to create an mnesia database for your yapp you can either try setting your yapp as an additional `bootstrap_yapp` in your server configuration, or just use the `yapp_ets_server` module instead. You can find instructions for using `yapp_ets_server` at the [top of its source file](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/blob/master/applications/yapp/src/yapp_ets_server.erl).

Comment: I already managed to get things working, after asking on the mailinglist. But thank you anyway. :).

Comment: @Viehzeug you could tell us what was the problem and how did you solve it in another answer, so it serves as reference for the future.